# xaml buttons inside dockpanel disappear

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, dockpanel

i have a datagrid, 3 buttons inside of a dockpanel. when the list of the datagrid filled the page, the vertical scroll appears and the 3 buttons disappear. even if you scroll all the way to the bottom, the buttons are not there.

```
<HeaderedContentControl>
    <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Associated WUCs for {0} ({1})">
                    <Binding Path="Class.Name" />
                    <Binding Path="Class.Narrative" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
        <m:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Style="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource DataGridButtonStyle}"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Image Style="{StaticResource DataGridButtonImageStyle}"
                                       Source="{StaticResource DeleteImage}" />
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Type entities:OtherClass}, ConverterParameter='Name', Converter={StaticResource DisplayNameConverter}}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    SortDirection="Ascending" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Type entities:OtherClass}, ConverterParameter='Narrative', Converter={StaticResource DisplayNameConverter}}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Narrative}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    SortDirection="Ascending" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            </m:DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource AddImage}"
                       Height="16" />
                <TextBlock Text=" Add" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding OkCommand}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                Content="OK" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                Content="Cancel"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </DockPanel>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

I would like the 3 buttons to go to the bottom and outside of the scrollbar when the scroll appears. i have tried using stackpanel, but that disable the scrollbar. i also tried to wrap the datagrid inside one dockpanel, and the 3 buttons inside of another dockpanel, but they don't seem to share the page and showing only the datagrid's lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i did was i wrap the the 3 buttons inside another dockpanel and dock it to the bottom. and i moved that dockpanel above the datagrid (very important).

The other way i solved this was changed the dockpanel to a grid and give it 2 rows, 1 for the datagrid, and the other for the 3 buttons (that got wrap around a stackpanel).

Comment: The first option worked perfectly. Nice one